# postgresql solution for a server failure

Tags: postgresql, hardware

i describe the situation:
i have two pc with postgressql server:
- a main pc, with ip 192.168.5.1 turned on
- a "backup" pc, with ip 192.168.5.1 turned off

i want that the main pc saves the two identical databases in local hard drive and on a nas real-time. when the main pc has a failure, i turn on, manually, the secondary pc, that reads the database from the nas

it's possible to do that?

postgres: postgresql-9.1
operating system: Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Please provide more details like postgres version and used operating systems.

Comment: Appears to be a re-post of http://serverfault.com/questions/439636/postgresql-access-to-same-data

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql supports replication between two servers. http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Binary_Replication_Tutorial

This can be done over the network between the two Postgresql installations running the two different servers.

But you can also run two instances of Postgresql on the same server (e.g one using the local disk and the other using the NAS storage). And configure replication between these instances.

Comment: thanks, i have already try this solution but when i access to the database on the nas from the secondary pc i don't found any data